# Como criar combobox no swift?

Tags: ios, swift

To querendo criar um comboBox para listar todos os cursos que o meu app oferece porem nao achei o componente correspondente, alias achei um ate parecido e implementei o PickerView, mas gostaria de reproduzir o comportamento padrao de um:

```html
<select>
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
  <option>Yellow</option>
</select>
```

E no meu fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu poderia reproduzir o mesmo comportamento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PickerView` é o componente nativo para esse tipo de ação no `iOS`

Você pode usar algumas soluções como [Collapse TableView](https://github.com/rob-nash/CollapsableOptions), ou uma adaptação de [UITextField + PickerView](https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker).

Uma solução interessante que encontrei utiliza [UITextField + Popover](https://github.com/sag333ar/SRKControls):

**Exemplo de uso:**

```
// Adicione um textfield no Storyboard e mude a classe dele para SRKComboBox.
@IBOutlet weak var myComboBox:SRKComboBox!

// Array qualquer
let arrayForComboBox = ["Sagar", "Sagar R. Kothari", "Kothari", "sag333ar", "sag333ar.github.io", "samurai", "jack", "cartoon", "network"]


//MARK:- UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  if let txt = textField as? SRKComboBox {
    txt.delegateForComboBox = self
    txt.showOptions()
    return false
  }
  if let txt = textField as? SRKDateTimeBox {
    txt.delegateForDateTimeBox = self
    txt.showOptions()
    return false
  }
  return true
}

//MARK:- SRKComboBoxDelegate
//Adicione os delegates

func comboBox(textField:SRKComboBox, didSelectRow row:Int) {
  if textField == self.myComboBox {
    self.myComboBox.text = self.arrayForComboBox[row]
  }
}

func comboBoxNumberOfRows(textField:SRKComboBox) -> Int {
  if textField == self.myComboBox {
    return self.arrayForComboBox.count
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}

func comboBox(textField:SRKComboBox, textForRow row:Int) -> String {
  if textField == self.myComboBox {
    return self.arrayForComboBox[row]
  } else {
    return ""
  }
}

func comboBoxPresentingViewController(textField:SRKComboBox) -> UIViewController {
  return self
}

func comboBoxRectFromWhereToPresent(textField:SRKComboBox) -> CGRect {
  return textField.frame
}

func comboBoxFromBarButton(textField:SRKComboBox) -> UIBarButtonItem? {
  return nil
}

func comboBoxTintColor(textField:SRKComboBox) -> UIColor {
  return UIColor.blackColor()
}

func comboBoxToolbarColor(textField:SRKComboBox) -> UIColor {
  return UIColor.whiteColor()
}

func comboBoxDidTappedCancel(textField:SRKComboBox) {
  textField.text = ""
}

func comboBoxDidTappedDone(textField:SRKComboBox) {
  print("Let's do some action here")
}
```

**Resultado esperado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]